# ssl on localhost and apache server

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, localhost

How do I do SSL on `localhost`?

How do I do it on live server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4221874/632951

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to SSL with HTTP, for testing purposes you need to create [a self-signed SSL certificate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html#selfcert).

However, you probably don't want your users to get a warning for self-signed cert, so for production environment you might want to get [a real, official CA signed certificate.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html#realcert)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Jawa, but for testing SSL on localhost, I would suggest you to look this post

[How to implement SSL (https) on localhost](http://labs.jweavers.com/posts/How_to_implement_SSL_%28https%29_on_localhost.php)

Comment: Link appears dead now

Answer (score 0):

SSL or SSH? I know some people have already given answers on this thread but you could be meaning SSH which is a login system which allows you to login to the server and perform CLI commands and allows you to execute commands and perform server maintenance from a remote location.

PuTTY is a good application of which you can use to connect remotely to a server.